# Count Zero and/or Non-Zero bytes in a bytea/string

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, bytea

I have a field in bytea format, and I'm trying to calculate how many zero bytes are in the field (postgresql).

**Example String:**

`0x202ee0ed0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000014370000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003f8affe7`

I originally tried to do this by counting how often `00` occurred, but this can be inaccurate since that doesn't check if it's a byte or two 0s that happen to be next to each other.

I'm currently using this `regex_replace` (found from another question) to force a `_` in between bytes so that I can then count `00` occurrences, but this slows down the query by multiple magnitudes vs a simple `replace` on the order of 100k-1m+ rows:
`regexp_replace(data::text, '(..)', E'\\1_', 'g')` - Produces something like `20_2e_e0...`

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a more performant way to count the number of zero or non-zero bytes in a bytea/string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no very simple and efficient way in SQL, I think. The best I can come up with is:

```
SELECT cardinality(
          string_to_array(
             encode('\xDEADF00D0000', 'escape'),
             '\000'
          )
       ) - 1;

 ?column? 
══════════
        2
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! After posting this, I found a similar answer from random experimenting (where `data` is my bytea string):

     `SELECT 
     COALESCE( (char_length( encode(data,'escape') ) - 
     char_length(REPLACE(encode(data,'escape'),'\000','')) ) /4 ,0) AS zero_bytes`

I need to learn more about how "escape" actually works to validate that it's correct, but I'll definitely see how performance compares to you solution as well. Thanks again!

Comment: That is also correct.