# Count Zero & Non-Zero Bytes in a String (Databricks SQL)

Tags: sql, databricks, databricks-sql

In a byte string, I'm trying to calculate how many bytes are zero `00` or non-zero (i.e. `ff`)

I've so far found this split / array function, but it has poor preformance (a few mins to run): `cardinality(array_remove(array_remove((split(data,'(?<=\\G..)')),'00'),''))-1`

**Example string** `0x13dcfc5900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003c63db09c669280000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003b5e789d00000000000000000000000042000000000000000000000000000000000000420000000000000000000000007f5c764cbc14f9669b88837ca1490cca17c31607000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004234893acac5096f4a1ad8fd952cc98b8c8ff460000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000062a398f9`

In postgresql, you could format as `escape`: [Count Zero and/or Non-Zero bytes in a bytea/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849459/count-zero-and-or-non-zero-bytes-in-a-bytea-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [unhex](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/unhex.html) function you won't need to bother about splitting.

```
SELECT length(s) - length(replace(s, chr(0), '')) as length_zero,
       length(replace(s, chr(0), '')) as length_non_zero
  FROM (SELECT decode(unhex('13dcfc590000'), 'US-ASCII') as s) _;

length_zero  length_non_zero
          2                4
```

Comment: You are a hero! This worked for me.